# Player is moving through the Wall in Unity 3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making a simple game where the Player moves only Horizontally and the Enemies spawn from front. I  created a Wall at the Left and Right side of the Player. But, Player keeps going through the Wall even when I have added Rigidbody component to Walls and Player. I used Cube gameobject to make a wall. Please help. Thank you!

Comment: you need to use colliders https://docs.unity3d.com/es/2019.4/Manual/CollidersOverview.html

Comment: I am sorry I forgot to mention, I have Colliders attached too to the Walls and Player. The Colliders size has been modified too but nothing seems to be working.

Comment: How are you moving your characters? There is a lot of info on colliders and their requirements about

Comment: I am using Horizontal input to move my Player horizontally.

Comment: That doesn’t answer the question. That tells me how your code knows to move your player not how your code moves it.

Answer (score 1):

1. Do you have collider on walls and on player?
2. If walls and player have colliders, check are theese colliders turned on and not triggers. (They should be turned on  and checkbox "Is trigger" should be false)
3. If previous steps completed and it still doesn't work, check Edit -> Project Settings -> Physics -> Layer collision matrix. And make sure that walls' layer collides with player's layer

Answer (score 0):

I have NavMesh agent on my player and what helped me:

1. Mark walls (and other static objects) as static in inspector
2. Go to Window->AI->Navigation and bake the scene

Answer (score 0):

Add Box Collider to the object to make it collide with the walls.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).